# Unable to run the default python app after installing Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I see the following error in the log file:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.pyc", line 486, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "launcher\taskthread.pyc", line 65, in run
  File "subprocess.pyc", line 594, in __init__
  File "subprocess.pyc", line 816, in _execute_child
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: I don't know much about app engine, but [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) is a Python library for launching executables. At first glance, it looks to me like the user running Python doesn't have privileges to launch the executable it's trying to.

Answer (score 2):

```
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

In Windows I used to see this error myself after installing Google App Engine SDK for PHP. This error occured when gae could not find the PHP executable.

The thing was I was specifying the absolute path to the folder that contained php-cgi.exe, leaving out the name of the executable php-cgi.exe! I solved this problem by adding the name of tyhe executable as well. So you might want to take a look again at your absolute path and make corrections.

from the docs:

> Start the web server with the following command, giving it the path to
>   your project directory:
>
> google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=absolute-path-to-php-cgi.exe myproject/

Hope it helps,